# Using 全員 （All students/All employees, etc.)

Tags: nuances, modification

I'm often translating phrases like "All employees must register," or "All team members have made efforts to...," etc.
It's a really basic question and I apologize if it has been addressed before, but I always wonder if I should be saying,
社員全員 /　全員の社員/　全社員　/各社員
What is the most natural way to express this?  Does it depend on the situation?

And I guess a follow-up question would be, what exactly is the nuance between 全 and 各 and in what situations would one be correct and one be incorrect?

I often write 全員の社員 but at best, it seems kind of clunky and at worst, just grammatically wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

全社員 or 各社員 sounds the most natural to me. Note you can do this with pretty much any noun, like 全生徒. 全員の社員 sounds redundant.

As for the difference between the use of 全- and 各-, the basic difference is that 全- means "all" and 各- means "each", I do believe the nuances of those two in English are similar. So you can use 全社員 for something like 「全社員、会議室に集合してください。」（All employees, gather in the meeting room.） and 各社員 like 「各社員、デスク周りを綺麗に片付けるように」(All (each) employee, make sure to keep your desk tidy.).